# Expectation of integral of non negative borel function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $h$ be a non negative borel function, and $H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}h(y)dy$. Let $X$ be a random variable. Prove that
$$ E[H(X)]  = \int h(y)\mathbb{P}(X>y)dy
$$

I know that $$E[H(X)] = \int_{\Omega} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x}h(y)dy\right)d\mathbb{P} $$. From change of variables, we can get

$$ E[H(X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x}h(y)dy\right) dF_X(x)
$$
where $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X<x)$. I was stuck at this step, any help would be appreciated. I suspect I have to use Fubini's theorem because of the double integral, but could not figure out how. Thanks.

Comment: Use the characteristic function $\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, x]}$ to remove the $x$ from the right limit of the inner integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variables is not right, it must be

$$
 \int_{\Omega } \left(\int_{-\infty}^{X(\omega )}h(y)dy\right) dP(\omega )= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x}h(y)dy\right) dF_X(x)
$$
Now, using Iverson brackets, you have that

$$
 \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{(-\infty,x]}h(y)dy dF_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}[y\leqslant x]h(y)d(y,F_X(x))
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{[y,\infty )}h(y)dF_X(x)dy\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [X\geqslant y]h(y)dy
$$

Comment: i don't understand, isn't my change of variables exactly the same as yours?

Comment: @Attila1177298 not exactly, you have written $x$ instead of $X(\omega )$

Answer (score 3):

Actually,
$$
\mathsf{E}H(X)=\int_{\Omega}\int 1\{X(\omega)>y\}h(y)\,dy\,d\mathsf{P}(\omega).
$$
Now, change the order of integrals (using [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)).